# Printing from IPad App

Tags: iphone, ipad, printing

Just wondering if there is a way to add functionality to my IPad app to print.

I know there seems to be a few apps out there now that allow you to print to a printer from your ipad but I just want to have a print button within my app that prints to a device.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, with AirPrint in iOS 4.2.

Not many printers are supported, but you can proxy through your Mac.

[Click here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW1) for the corresponding page in the Developer Documentation.